# How to define variable in two npm command?

Tags: npm, webpack

As I have different channel to run my code in npm command.

In the npm scripts, I will write

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server",
  "start:channle_1": "CHANNEL=channe_1 webpack-dev-server",
  "start:channle_2": "CHANNEL=channe_2 webpack-dev-server"
}
```

And in `webpack.config.js`, I can define variable to judge I'm in which channel.

```
  const CHANNEL = process.env.CHANNEL || 'channe_1';

  console.log('===', process.env.CHANNEL);

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      CHANNEL: JSON.stringify(CHANNEL),
    })
  );
```

So, in my code, there is a glable `CHANNEL` I can use.

But, there is a problem in my npm scripts. I want separate sever and channel.I hope it can like this

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server",
  "start:channle_1": "CHANNEL=channe_1 & npm run start",
  "start:channle_2": "CHANNEL=channe_2 & npm run start"
}
```

As I know, `&` can let npm command run currently, but, in my situation, the variable `CHANNEL` can't pass in `process.env.CHANNEL`.

So, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you take out the `&` it should work fine:

```
"start:channle_1": "CHANNEL=channe_1 npm run start"
```

When you put `&` in there, it's going to try to run the preceding (empty) command in the background. You can set environment variables by prefixing them from the command, separated by whitespace.

Comment: Should also add that if you want your script to work on windows, you will have to use https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env.